# Omitting the relative pronoun "that"

Tags: word-usage, relative-pronouns

I came across this sentence while surfing on the Internet:

> Now I'm calculating how many pages I should do per day (that) would be reasonable.

When read out loud, the sentence sounds sort of natural, but grammatically speaking, it's wrong because after the verb "to calculate" isn't a clause but a noun.

Should the word "that" be added back in to the sentence, or is the sentence itself not wrong in the first place?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical both with "that" and without it. The following two sentences are grammatical: 1. Now I'm calculating how many pages I should do per day. 2. Now I'm calculating how many pages would be reasonable. If the meanings of both are to be combined into one sentence, a re-write is needed. Here is one way to say it: 3. Now I'm calculating how many pages per day it would be reasonable for me to do.

Comment: Rosie F Could you explain why the sentence with that is ungrammatical? I might not go with it myself because it doesn't sound better but I am not sure how it's ungrammatical.

Comment: @Pkjmm For me it's ungrammatical because the phrase 'that would be reasonable' is split away from the rest of the phrase of which it is a part (how many pages). Grammatically you would get away with "I'm calculating how many pages it would be reasonable that I should do per day" but that sounds horrible and about 150 years out of date. Grammatical correctness is a prerequisite of good English, not a complete definition of it.

Comment: "Now I'm calculating how many pages per day would be reasonable" is grammatical; I think the problem is you have the construction "how many X is enough"/"how many X I should do"/"how many X would be reasonable", where X is a noun phrase ("pages per day"), but you can't just go putting multiple modifiers on the end of it.

Comment: The sentence as is refers to a day being reasonable -- it's a misplaced modifer problem. The above comments show good ways to fix it.